# What is the best way to host JavaScript libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, service, libraries

Are there any existing solutions for hosting JavaScript libraries like Google does with jQuery?

If not, what is the best way to host them? Also how can these files be protected without proper retrieval of them (i.e. a login to the server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more about [CDN - Content Delivery Network](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network&ei=E6CqUeOwEYeGhQetqID4Ag&usg=AFQjCNGV5YDfGmqtA7qo2GOdUSpAZs-wBQ&sig2=4LDlko794vsNNvX356vt2g&bvm=bv.47244034,d.ZG4)